# selectOneMenu - select item by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `p:selectOnemenu`

```
<p:selectOneMenu>        
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="white" itemValue="white" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="red" itemValue="red" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

How can I select option `red` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your widgetVar name is `selectOneMenuWV`, you can select the item based on the label:

```
PF('selectOneMenuWV').selectItem($('.ui-selectonemenu-item[data-label*="red"]'));
```

Comment: thanks=) I will use my implementation but accept yours as answer cause it is more correct to specific case=)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with h:selectOneMenu:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{addnewfields.color}"  
                 styleClass="colorSelect" >
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="red" itemValue="red" />
   <f:selectItem itemLabel=" white" itemValue="white" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and js:

```
$('.colorSelect').val('red')
```